# sudo apt-get install apache2 does not fetch apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, package-management, aptitude

Trying out sudo apt-get install apache2
This is what I get

```
root@x27:/home/test# sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package apache2
```

Appreciate help for using apt-get for apache

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

First you should search for the package: 
`apt-cache search apache` 
`aptitude search apache` .
However, apache2 is the correct package. You should do a `sudo apt-get update` and if it won't fix it, check your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. (Post it to pastebin.com and give us the link if you cant figure it out.)